# "Unrouteable address" with exim4

Tags: exim, exim4

I am using exim4. I have a Wordpress installation with a contact form. My hostname -f is mydomain.com.

The form is sending an email to info@mydomain.com. However it never reaches my "off site" email. How can I set this up so the email does not get stuck on the webserver?

Exim should forward (route) the email to the off site email info@mydomain.com. When I send from, for example, gmail to that address it gets delivered right away.

I have followed this guide: https://library.linode.com/email/exim/send-only-mta-debian-6-squeeze but it didnt help with this issue.

```
mydomain:/var/mail# exim -bt -d info@mydomain.com 2>&1
Exim version 4.80 uid=0 gid=0 pid=23864 D=fbb95cfd
Berkeley DB: Berkeley DB 5.1.29: (October 25, 2011)
Support for: crypteq iconv() IPv6 GnuTLS move_frozen_messages DKIM
Lookups (built-in): lsearch wildlsearch nwildlsearch iplsearch cdb dbm dbmjz dbmnz dnsdb dsearch nis nis0 passwd
Authenticators: cram_md5 plaintext
Routers: accept dnslookup ipliteral manualroute queryprogram redirect
Transports: appendfile/maildir/mailstore autoreply lmtp pipe smtp
Fixed never_users: 0
Size of off_t: 8
Compiler: GCC [4.7.2]
Library version: GnuTLS: Compile: 2.12.20
                         Runtime: 2.12.20
Library version: PCRE: Compile: 8.31
                       Runtime: 8.30 2012-02-04
Total 13 lookups
WHITELIST_D_MACROS: "OUTGOING"
TRUSTED_CONFIG_LIST: "/etc/exim4/trusted_configs"
changed uid/gid: forcing real = effective
  uid=0 gid=0 pid=23864
  auxiliary group list: <none>
seeking password data for user "uucp": cache not available
getpwnam() succeeded uid=10 gid=10
changed uid/gid: calling tls_validate_require_cipher
  uid=106 gid=109 pid=23865
  auxiliary group list: <none>
tls_validate_require_cipher child 23865 ended: status=0x0
configuration file is /var/lib/exim4/config.autogenerated
log selectors = 00000ffc 00612001
trusted user
admin user
seeking password data for user "mail": cache not available
getpwnam() succeeded uid=8 gid=8
user name "root" extracted from gecos field "root"
originator: uid=0 gid=0 login=root name=root
sender address = root@mydomain.com
Address testing: uid=0 gid=109 euid=0 egid=109
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
Testing info@mydomain.com
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
Considering info@mydomain.com
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
routing info@mydomain.com
--------> hubbed_hosts router <--------
local_part=info domain=mydomain.com
checking domains
expansion of "${if exists{/etc/exim4/hubbed_hosts}{partial-lsearch;/etc/exim4/hubbed_hosts}fail}" forced failure: assume not in this list
hubbed_hosts router skipped: domains mismatch
--------> dnslookup_relay_to_domains router <--------
local_part=info domain=mydomain.com
checking domains
mydomain.com in "@:localhost:localhost:localhost.localdomain:mydomain.com"? yes (matched "@")
mydomain.com in "! +local_domains : +relay_to_domains"? no (matched "! +local_domains")
dnslookup_relay_to_domains router skipped: domains mismatch
--------> dnslookup router <--------
local_part=info domain=mydomain.com
checking domains
cached yes match for +local_domains
cached lookup data = NULL
mydomain.com in "! +local_domains"? no (matched "! +local_domains" - cached)
dnslookup router skipped: domains mismatch
--------> real_local router <--------
local_part=info domain=mydomain.com
real_local router skipped: prefix mismatch
--------> system_aliases router <--------
local_part=info domain=mydomain.com
checking domains
cached yes match for +local_domains
cached lookup data = NULL
mydomain.com in "+local_domains"? yes (matched "+local_domains" - cached)
R: system_aliases for info@mydomain.com
calling system_aliases router
rda_interpret (string): ${lookup{$local_part}lsearch{/etc/aliases}}
search_open: lsearch "/etc/aliases"
search_find: file="/etc/aliases"
  key="info" partial=-1 affix=NULL starflags=0
LRU list:
  7/etc/aliases
  End
internal_search_find: file="/etc/aliases"
  type=lsearch key="info"
file lookup required for info
  in /etc/aliases
lookup failed
expanded:
file is not a filter file
parse_forward_list:
system_aliases router declined for info@mydomain.com
--------> userforward router <--------
local_part=info domain=mydomain.com
checking domains
cached yes match for +local_domains
cached lookup data = NULL
mydomain.com in "+local_domains"? yes (matched "+local_domains" - cached)
checking for local user
seeking password data for user "info": cache not available
getpwnam() returned NULL (user not found)
userforward router skipped: info is not a local user
--------> procmail router <--------
local_part=info domain=mydomain.com
checking domains
cached yes match for +local_domains
cached lookup data = NULL
mydomain.com in "+local_domains"? yes (matched "+local_domains" - cached)
checking for local user
seeking password data for user "info": using cached result
getpwnam() returned NULL (user not found)
procmail router skipped: info is not a local user
--------> maildrop router <--------
local_part=info domain=mydomain.com
checking domains
cached yes match for +local_domains
cached lookup data = NULL
mydomain.com in "+local_domains"? yes (matched "+local_domains" - cached)
checking for local user
seeking password data for user "info": using cached result
getpwnam() returned NULL (user not found)
maildrop router skipped: info is not a local user
--------> lowuid_aliases router <--------
local_part=info domain=mydomain.com
checking domains
cached yes match for +local_domains
cached lookup data = NULL
mydomain.com in "+local_domains"? yes (matched "+local_domains" - cached)
checking for local user
seeking password data for user "info": using cached result
getpwnam() returned NULL (user not found)
lowuid_aliases router skipped: info is not a local user
--------> local_user router <--------
local_part=info domain=mydomain.com
checking domains
cached yes match for +local_domains
cached lookup data = NULL
mydomain.com in "+local_domains"? yes (matched "+local_domains" - cached)
checking local_parts
info in "! root"? yes (end of list)
checking for local user
seeking password data for user "info": using cached result
getpwnam() returned NULL (user not found)
local_user router skipped: info is not a local user
--------> mail4root router <--------
local_part=info domain=mydomain.com
checking domains
cached yes match for +local_domains
cached lookup data = NULL
mydomain.com in "+local_domains"? yes (matched "+local_domains" - cached)
checking local_parts
info in "root"? no (end of list)
mail4root router skipped: local_parts mismatch
no more routers
info@mydomain.com is undeliverable: Unrouteable address
search_tidyup called
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> Exim pid=23864 terminating with rc=2 >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you tried this from your server

> echo "test mail." | mail -s Test name@mydomain.com

Also make sure that your hostname is a fully qualified domain.

try

> hostname
>
> hostname -i

hostname should resolve or point correctly to IP shown by hostname -i(main IP)

Also check that the MX record of mydomain.com and make sure that its using local mail server.

Comment: Nope. 127.0.0.1 is a localhost loop IP. You can't send mail using this IP. Your hostname must be resolvable. It should point to a public IP. Thats what meant by fully qualified domain name.

Comment: Hi @LeoPrince do you have a reference where we can confirm that `hostname -i` should return a public ip?

Comment: My previous comment was posted couple of years ago, when I was a beginner.. I would like to modify that comment a bit now. hostname -i brings out the IP by resolving the DNS.. Either it should be FQDN to resolve recursively using nameserver or it should have a entry in hosts file. Some server vendors provide public IP directly in hosts file but some provide private IPs, it depends on how the system they manages. However what I meant to say is, hostname -i should bring you the available resolving IP, either from hosts file, if it has entry or from DNS.. Hopes that helps

Comment: mail is not on all exim hosts, what is the test supposed to do?

Answer (score 8):

According to the [Testing Exim](https://github.com/Exim/exim/wiki/TestingExim) wiki you can check the routing of an address by using:

```
exim -bt name@example.org
```

This will give you information about if exim4 recognises this address.